# How to call variables from another class

Tags: java, object, output, syntax-error, logic

I just finished my java code when i run it it doesnt output any values.
I have two classes one class where i use jOption to input valuesand another class that uses the first classes input values to calculate interest.

Class 1:

```
    public class Employee_Details {
    
 String custName;
 String custNuum;
 String priice;
 String Month;
 int custNum;
 double price;
 int reMonth;
 double total;
 double reAmount;
 
    
    public void getDetails (){
        
       Finance_Period fin1 = new Finance_Period();
        
        custName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter Customer Name");
         custNuum = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter Customer Number");
        custNum = Integer.parseInt(custNuum);
     priice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter price of product");
     price = Double.parseDouble(priice);
        Month = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter number of repayment months");
        reMonth = Integer.parseInt(Month);
        
         reAmount = price/reMonth;
        
          if (reMonth >3){
            fin1.getInterest();
          }
            else  {
              total = price;
              
             
              
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Customer Name: " + custName + "\n" + "Customer Conatct: " + custNum + "\n" + "Product Amount: " + "R"+price + "\n" + "Repayment Months: " + reMonth + "\n" +"Monthly Repayments: " + "R" +reAmount + "\n" + "Total Due: " + "R" + total  ); 
          }
           
        
         
         
       
       
       
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Second Class:

```
public class Finance_Period {
   
double interest;
String name;
int num;
double product;
double amount;



public double getInterest(){
    Employee_Details cust1 = new Employee_Details();
    
    
   
   
   
   
        interest = (0.25 * cust1.reAmount) + cust1.reAmount;
       
           
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Customer Name: " + cust1.custName+ "\n" + "Customer Conatct: " + cust1.custNum + "\n" + "Product Amount: " + "R"+cust1.price + "\n" + "Repayment Months: " + cust1.reMonth + "\n" +"Monthly Repayments: " + "R" + cust1.reAmount + "\n" + "Total:" + "R" + (cust1.reAmount + interest) );
        
    
    return interest;
```

in the first class there is an if statement that says if repay months is greater than 3 run other method and once i input a number greater than 3 it will run the getinterest method but the output is :

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IL1Y6.png)

i believe i did not link the 2 classes correctly but i do not know what else to do,
I cant seem to find the logic error here please help me out

this is my main class

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
Employee_Details cust1 = new Employee_Details();
cust1.getDetails();
 Finance_Period fin1 = new Finance_Period();
 
 
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Customer Name: " + cust1.custName+ "\n" + "Customer Conatct: " + cust1.custNum + "\n" + "Product Amount: " + "R"+cust1.price + "\n" + "Repayment Months: " + cust1.reMonth + "\n" +"Monthly Repayments: " + "R" + cust1.reAmount + "\n" + "Total:" + "R" + (cust1.reAmount + fin1.interest) );
```

}

Comment: You don't have constructors, getters or setters in the code that you showed us. When you do something like `Employee_Details cust1 = new Employee_Details();` the fields of the `Employee_Details` class are not initialized to any value provided by you or the user of your program, therefore when you access those fields, like when you do `cust1.reAmount`, what do you expect will happen? Also, you don't call any methods from one class in the other class. And you haven't shown us your main class, and neither of your classes have a `main()` method, so we don't even know how you are running this.

Comment: i have 3 classes employee details , interest and the main, so for my methods i should use getters and setters right?

Comment: That barely addresses one of the many things I said in my comment. You should edit the question to include the code of the Main class and try to address the other points I made.

Comment: i have shown you the main method its the last bit of code. i implemented getters and setters now im trying to link what i have in employee details to the interest class

Comment: Again, you don't have constructors in your classes. What details do you expect to get when you haven't given any meaningful values to the fields of your classes? At this point, the best advice I can give you is "go read about the basics of Java development before you continue writing code".

Comment: I used your tips thank you so much, i used the getters and setters and it made my code more effiecient and easier, what i ended up doing is taking the getinterest method and use it in one class instead of a different one, and the output and everything is running perfectly fine, thank you once again i never knew getters and setters would make coding much easier.